# Soft keyboard overlap of the screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Let me first describe the page---

I have `EditText` which is used to filter a `ListView` just below it. Below the list there is an `Google ad`.

In my manifest file, I have used

```
android:windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan or adjustResize
```

The page is like---

```
EditText
  ---
ListView
  ---
Google ad
```

When the editText is clicked the `soft keyboard` come up.
its below the editText.The ad comes up above the soft keyboard.
SO whatever i search is being overlapped by the google ad.

the list is  being covered up by the ad and so the user is not able to see the filterd list if he does not cancel the soft keyboard!
 How do i show the list as well as the ad?

Comment: Hide the ad when EditText is clicked? adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: I can do that. But is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: It also depends on the screen size. I am not aware of any methods other than the above.

Comment: You can use an Alphabet indexer instead of providing an EditText. That way no keyboard and no ad hiding.

Comment: umm.. that can be done... But i dont thik that would be good.Because list would not contain more than 10items...max 15items. I better hide the ad :(

Comment: Items? As in, an alphabet indexer works on the principle of caching. You dont have to worry about the number of items but the contents.